# Derivative of a multiple sum of matrix elements

Tags: derivatives

I have an array $V_{N*K}$ in which the sum of elemnts in each column is equal to 1. I have a function defined over the elements of this matrix which is

$$
F=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{l=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^KV_{jk}\log\frac{V_{jk}}{V_{lk}}+V_{lk}\log\frac{V_{lk}}{V_{jk}}
$$

The question is what is the derivative of this function, $F$ with respect to an element of array $V$, For instance $V_{1,1}$

Comment: Partial derivative, or total derivative?

Comment: partial derivative